# Output pdf not working on new server with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a CRM for a couple of years working perfect with the TCPDF and I put in a new server and now I have some problems (the code is exactly the same in both of servers).

This is the code generating the PDF :

```html
<?php
//Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$id_facture = $_POST['id_facture'];
$id_client = $_POST['id_client'];
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

 //Page header
 public function Header() {
  // Logo
  $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo.jpg';
  $this->Image($image_file, 18, 5, 80, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', true, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
  
 }

 // Page footer
 public function Footer() {
 
 $total = $this->getAliasNbPages();
 
 //if($this->getAliasNumPage() == $total){
 $info_bank = GET_bank_account();
 
 if($bank['clearing'] != ''){$clearing = '<br>Clearing : '.$bank['clearing'];}
  // Set font
  $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
  
  $txt_footer = '<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2"><tr>
 <td>'.NOM_SOCIETE.'<br>
 '.ADRESSE_SOCIETE.' - '.CODE_POSTAL_SOCIETE.'-'.VILLE_SOCIETE.'</td>';
 while($bank = mysqli_fetch_array($info_bank)){
  $txt_footer .= '
      <td>'.$bank['nom'].'<br>IBAN : '.$bank['iban'].'<br>BIC : '.$bank['bic'].'<br>'.$bank['type'].' : '.$bank['compte'].' '.$clearing.'
   </td></tr>';
   }
   $txt_footer .= '<tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"> '.MORE_INFO_SOCIETE.'</td>';
  
     $txt_footer .= '</tr></table><hr>';
  $txt_footer = ($txt_footer);
  if($this->getNumPages() == 1){
   $this->SetY(-30);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 9);
    $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, 'Informations bancaires', array('B' => array('width' => 0.4, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'round', 'dash' => 0, 'phase' => 1, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0))), 0, 0, true, 'J', true);
    $this->Ln(5);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $this->writeHTML($txt_footer, true, false, true, false, '');
    
  }else{
   if ($this->getPage() > 1){
    $this->SetY(-30);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 9);
    $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, 'Informations bancaires', array('B' => array('width' => 0.4, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'round', 'dash' => 0, 'phase' => 1, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0))), 0, 0, true, 'J', true);
    $this->Ln(5);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $this->writeHTML($txt_footer, true, false, true, false, '');
    //$this->Ln(5);
    //$this->Cell(0, 5, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), '', false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
   }else{
    $this->SetY(-10);
    $this->Cell(0, 5, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 'T', false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
   }
  }
  
  //}
 }


    public function MultiRowIntervention($firstC, $secondC, $thirdC, $fourthC) {
  
        $page_start = $this->getPage();
        $y_start = $this->GetY();

        // write the 1 cell
        $this->MultiCell(25, 0, $firstC, 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_1 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_1 = $this->GetY();
        $this->setPage($page_start);

        // write the 2 cell
        $this->writeHTMLCell(130, 0, 35, $y_start, ($secondC), 0, 1, 0, 'L' );
        $page_end_2 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_2 = $this->GetY(); 
  $this->setPage($page_start);
  
  // write the 3 cell
        $this->MultiCell(25, 0, $thirdC, 0, 'L', 0, 1, 165 ,$y_start, true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_3 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_3 = $this->GetY();
   $this->setPage($page_start);
  
  // write the 4 cell
        $this->MultiCell(20, 0, $fourthC, 0, 'R', 0, 1, 175 ,$y_start, true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_4 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_4 = $this->GetY();

        // set the new row position by case
        if (max($page_end_1,$page_end_2,$page_end_3,$page_end_4) == $page_start) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_1, $y_end_2, $page_end_3, $page_end_4);
        } elseif ($page_end_1 == $page_end_2) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_1, $y_end_2);
        } elseif ($page_end_2 == $page_end_3) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_2, $y_end_3);
  }elseif ($page_end_3 == $page_end_4) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_3, $y_end_4);
  } elseif ($page_end_1 > $page_end_2) {
            $ynew = $y_end_1;
        } elseif($page_end_2 > $page_end_3) {
            $ynew = $y_end_2;
        } elseif($page_end_3 > $page_end_4) {
            $ynew = $y_end_3;
        }else{
   $ynew = $y_end_4;
  }
  
        $this->setPage(max($page_end_1,$page_end_2));
        $this->SetXY($this->GetX(),$ynew);
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 public function MultiRowMateriel($firstC, $secondC, $thirdC, $fourthC, $fifthC) {
  
        $page_start = $this->getPage();
        $y_start = $this->GetY();

        // write the 1 cell
        $this->MultiCell(25, 0, $firstC, 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_1 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_1 = $this->GetY();
        $this->setPage($page_start);

        // write the 2 cell
  $this->writeHTMLCell(115, 0, 35, $y_start, ($secondC), 0, 1, 0, 'L' );
        //$this->MultiCell(115, 0, ($secondC), 0, 'L', 0, 1, 35,$y_start, true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_2 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_2 = $this->GetY(); 
   $this->setPage($page_start);
  
  // write the 3 cell
        $this->MultiCell(15, 0, $thirdC, 0, 'C', 0, 1, 150 ,$y_start, true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_3 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_3 = $this->GetY();
  $this->setPage($page_start);
  
  // write the 4 cell
        $this->MultiCell(25, 0, $fourthC, 0, 'R', 0, 1, 153 ,$y_start, true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_4 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_4 = $this->GetY();
  $this->setPage($page_start);
  
  // write the 5 cell
        $this->MultiCell(20, 0, $fifthC, 0, 'R', 0, 1, 175 ,$y_start, true, 'B', 0);
        $page_end_5 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_5 = $this->GetY();

        // set the new row position by case
        if (max($page_end_1,$page_end_2,$page_end_3,$page_end_4,$page_end_5) == $page_start) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_1, $y_end_2, $page_end_3, $page_end_4, $page_end_5);
        } elseif ($page_end_1 == $page_end_2) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_1, $y_end_2);
        } elseif ($page_end_2 == $page_end_3) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_2, $y_end_3);
  }elseif ($page_end_3 == $page_end_4) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_3, $y_end_4);
  }elseif ($page_end_4 == $page_end_5) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_4, $y_end_5);
  } elseif ($page_end_1 > $page_end_2) {
            $ynew = $y_end_1;
        } elseif($page_end_2 > $page_end_3) {
            $ynew = $y_end_2;
        } elseif($page_end_3 > $page_end_4) {
            $ynew = $y_end_3;
        }elseif($page_end_4 > $page_end_5) {
            $ynew = $y_end_4;
        }else{
   $ynew = $y_end_5;
  }
  
        $this->setPage(max($page_end_1,$page_end_2,$page_end_3,$page_end_4,$page_end_5));
        $this->SetXY($this->GetX(),$ynew);
    }
 
  public function MultiRow($left, $right) {
        // MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=0, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0)

        $page_start = $this->getPage();
        $y_start = $this->GetY();

        // write the left cell
        $this->MultiCell(150, 0, $left, 0, 'R', 0, 2, '', '', true,true,true, 0);

        $page_end_1 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_1 = $this->GetY();

        $this->setPage($page_start);

        // write the right cell
        $this->MultiCell(0, 0, $right, 0, 'R', 0, 1, $this->GetX() ,$y_start, true,true,true, 0);

        $page_end_2 = $this->getPage();
        $y_end_2 = $this->GetY();

        // set the new row position by case
        if (max($page_end_1,$page_end_2) == $page_start) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_1, $y_end_2);
        } elseif ($page_end_1 == $page_end_2) {
            $ynew = max($y_end_1, $y_end_2);
        } elseif ($page_end_1 > $page_end_2) {
            $ynew = $y_end_1;
        } else {
            $ynew = $y_end_2;
        }

        $this->setPage(max($page_end_1,$page_end_2));
        $this->SetXY($this->GetX(),$ynew);
    }

}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor(NOM_SOCIETE);
$pdf->SetTitle('Facture '.$id_facture);
//$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
//$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData('logo.jpg', PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('arial');

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 40, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 35);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
 $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//require_once('../../../gestion_user_fns.php');
 $no_client = no_client($id_facture);
 $nom_client = nom_client($no_client);
 $no_tel_client = no_tel_client($no_client);
 $email_client = email_client($no_client);
 $date_facture = inverse_date(date_facture($id_facture));
 $entreprise_client = entreprise_client($no_client);
 $date = date('d.m.Y');

  $adresse_client = adresse_client($no_client);
  $npa_client = npa_client($no_client);

  $total_inter_ht = total_inter($id_facture);
  $total_inter_TVA = total_inter_TVA($id_facture);
  $total_mat_HT = total_mat($id_facture);
  $total_mat_TVA = total_mat_TVA($id_facture);
  $rabais = rabais($id_facture);
  $nombre = GET_liste_mat_fact($id_facture);
  $nombre = mysqli_fetch_array($nombre);
  $total_HT = arrondi(total($id_facture));
  $total_TVA = arrondi(total_TVA($id_facture));
  if(mode_paiement($id_facture) != ""){
   $mode_paiement = mode_paiement($id_facture);
  }else{
   $mode_paiement = "30 jours";
  }
  
  $total_TTC = arrondi(total($id_facture)+total_TVA($id_facture) - $rabais);
  
 if ($entreprise_client != '-') {$info_client[0] = $entreprise_client.'<br>';}
 if ($nom_client != ' ') {$info_client[1] = $nom_client."<br>";}
 $info_client[2] = $adresse_client.'<br>';
 $info_client[3] = $npa_client.'<br>';
 
 
 $list_acompte = GET_acompte_PAR_id_facture($id_facture);
 
 //echo $id_facture;
if($list_acompte){
  
 $montant_acompte = 0;
  $taxe_acompte = 0;
  while($acom = mysqli_fetch_array($list_acompte)){
   $montant_acompte += $acom['montant'];
   $taxe_acompte += $acom['taxe'];
  }
  $totalAcompte = arrondi($montant_acompte + $taxe_acompte);
  $total_HT = arrondi(total($id_facture) + $montant_acompte);
  $total_TVA = arrondi(total_TVA($id_facture) + $taxe_acompte);
  $total_TTC = arrondi(total($id_facture)+total_TVA($id_facture) + $montant_acompte + $taxe_acompte - $rabais);
 $totalPayer = arrondi($total_TTC - $totalAcompte);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
ob_start();

// set some text to print

if(FAX_SOCIETE != ''){ $fax_societe = 'T&eacute;l&eacute;fax '.FAX_SOCIETE.'<br>';}
if(NUMERO_TVA_SOCIETE != ''){ $numero_tva_societe = 'N&deg; de TVA :  '.NUMERO_TVA_SOCIETE.'<br>';}
// create some HTML content
$html = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">'.$info_client[0].$info_client[1].$info_client[2].($info_client[3]).'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div style="">'.NOM_SOCIETE.'<br>
'.ADRESSE_SOCIETE.' '.NUMERO_SOCIETE.'<br>
'.PAYS_SOCIETE.'-'.CODE_POSTAL_SOCIETE.'&nbsp;'.VILLE_SOCIETE.'
<br>T&eacute;l&eacute;phone '.TELEPHONE_1_SOCIETE.'<br>
'.$fax_societe.EMAIL_SOCIETE.'<br>
'.LIEN_SOCIETE.'<br>'.$numero_tva_societe.'</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
  <b>Date : '.$date_facture.'</b><br>
  <b>Facture N&deg; : '.$id_facture.'</b><br>
  Paiement :  '.strip_tags($mode_paiement).'
 </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span style="font-size:20px;"><b>FACTURE</b></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->Ln(1);
$html = ($html);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


$borderDashedBottom = array('T' => array('width' => 0.1, 'cap' => 'square', 'join' => 'round', 'dash' => 2, 'phase' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0)));
$borderSolidBottom = array('B' => array('width' => 0.4, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'round', 'dash' => 0, 'phase' => 1, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0)));


$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
//=========================================================================================================
//---------------------------------------------------------- INTERVENTIONS
//=========================================================================================================

$list_intervention_facture = GET_liste_inter_fact($id_facture);
 
if ($intervention = mysqli_num_rows($list_intervention_facture) != 0){

 if(tva_societe($no_client) || tva_facture($id_facture)) $txt_prix = 'Prix HT';else $txt_prix = 'Prix TTC';
 
 $pdf->Multicell(0, 5, 'Intervention(s)', $borderSolidBottom, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);
 $pdf->Ln(1);

 $pdf->MultiRowIntervention('Date', 'Description', 'Durée', $txt_prix);
 $pdf->Ln(-3);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, '', $borderSolidBottom, 0, 0, true, 'J', true); 
 $pdf->Ln(5);
 

   while ($inter = mysqli_fetch_array($list_intervention_facture))
  {
  $description = $inter[1];
   if ($inter[2] == 0)
    $temps = '-';
   elseif ($inter[2] >= 60)
   {
    $heure = $inter[2] / 60;
    $minute = $inter[2] % 60;
    if ($minute == 0)
     $temps = (int)$heure . 'h';
    else
     $temps = (int)$heure . 'h ' . $minute . 'm';
   }
   else
    $temps = $inter[2].'m';
    $date = inverse_date($inter[0]);
    if(tva_societe($no_client) || tva_facture($id_facture))
      $prix = arrondi($inter[3]);
    else
      $prix = arrondi($inter[3]+$inter[5]);
    
 $pdf->MultiRowIntervention($date, ($description)."\n", $temps, $prix);
 $pdf->Ln(0.5);
 
 // write the line bottom
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, '', $borderDashedBottom, 0, 0, true, 'J', true); 
 $pdf->Ln(0.5);
 $pdf->checkPageBreak(1, '', true);
  }
   
   $pdf->Ln(10);
}

//=========================================================================================================
//---------------------------------------------------------- MATERIELS
//=========================================================================================================

if($intervention){$nL = $nL + 10;}
$list_materiel_facture = GET_liste_mat_fact($id_facture);
 
 if ($materiel = mysqli_num_rows($list_materiel_facture) != 0)
 {

 if(tva_societe($no_client) || tva_facture($id_facture)) $txt_prix = 'Prix HT';else $txt_prix = 'Prix TTC';

 $pdf->Multicell(0, 5, 'Materiel(s)', $borderSolidBottom, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);
 $pdf->Ln(1);

 $pdf->MultiRowMateriel('Date', 'Description', 'Nombre', 'Unitaire', $txt_prix);
 $pdf->Ln(-3);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, '', $borderSolidBottom, 0, 0, true, 'J', true); 
 $pdf->Ln(5);

 while ($mat = mysqli_fetch_array($list_materiel_facture))
  {
   $date = inverse_date($mat[0]);
   $desc = strip_tags($mat[3]." - ".$mat[4]);
   
   if(tva_societe($no_client) || tva_facture($id_facture)){
    $prix_total = $mat[1] * $mat[5];
    $prix = $mat[1];
   }else{
    $prix_total = ($mat[1] + $mat[2]) * $mat[5];
    $prix = $mat[1] + $mat[2];
     }
    
    
 $pdf->MultiRowMateriel($date, ($desc), $mat[5], arrondi($prix), arrondi($prix_total));
 $pdf->Ln(0.5);
 // write the line bottom
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, '', $borderDashedBottom, 0, 0, true, 'J', true); 
 $pdf->Ln(0.5);
  }
 
   
}
//------------------------------------------------ LES TOTAUX
$pdf->checkPageBreak(20, '', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, '', $borderSolidBottom, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);



 
 
if(tva_societe($no_client)) {
 $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->MultiRow('Total HT CHF', $total_HT);
    
 
    if(tva_facture($id_facture)){
     $txt_tva = 'Vente hors Taxe (TVA 0%) CHF';
 }else{
  $txt_tva = 'TVA (7.7%) CHF';
 }
 
   $pdf->MultiRow($txt_tva, $total_TVA);

}


if ($rabais){ 
    
 $pdf->MultiRow('Rabais CHF', '- '.arrondi($rabais));

 }

$pdf->MultiRow('<b>Prix Total TTC CHF</b>', '<b>'.$total_TTC.'</b>');


if($montant_acompte != 0){

 $pdf->MultiRow('Acomptes CHF', '- '.$totalAcompte);
 $pdf->MultiRow('<b>Total &agrave; payer</b>', '<b>'.$totalPayer.'</b>');
}
$pdf->Ln(-3);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $y_start, '', $borderSolidBottom, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('pdf/factures_pdf/facture_'.$id_facture.'_'.$date_facture.'.pdf', 'F');


//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

So, now I'm having the followins errors :

*Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in*

and

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in*

I read somewere that's a problem with the HTML tags and I need to clean up with a tool like HTML tidy but, the code is almost in PHP and I've look for something missing and I can't found it.

There's someone who can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Simple and usefull option is run the same code in old server if you have access get the `html` output in a variable, copy the `html` and validate on here `https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input` this website will validate your markup if you have something `missing/extra` for html tags. else set `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` on the top of this php file

Comment: Hi, thanks for the anwser, but the output is not a html, is a PDF.

Comment: PDF is generated by your html :) so get your html and validate it